# Why are all user's StackExchange accounts visible?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, user-accounts

The profile page is displaying all the user participating accounts.

Is it not too much that a user can know all the interests of each user?

Comment: This is only true if a user linked their accounts. Nothing is stopping people from using **different** logins on different sites and not link them.

Comment: @Oded Worth noting that quite often, people end up accidentally getting those accounts merged by changing the email address and forgetting, or adding the wrong login, etc. Nothing is currently stopping them, but it's not something we actively support - kind of a swim at your own risk sort of thing. If you accidentally add the wrong email in the wrong place, we can't help it if your participation on a religious site is visible from your more professional profile on another site (I know this is less than optimal, but worth noting for folks just in case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see there is a new feature: you can hide the communities you don't want other to see, in the `Edit Profile & Settings` tab.

I don't know if its from my inspiration or not, anyway its a nice and can be useful feature.

Answer (score 7):

In general, even if you *don't* link your accounts between different sites, your user profile still, deliberately, reveals quite a lot about which topics *within* the scope of, say, SO you're interested it.

That said, I can understand your concern.  Sure, I *could* imagine a situation where, for example, I might not want a prospective employer know that I can write PHP, but that's a pretty minor and contrived scenario compared to having your SO profile reveal your [hobbies](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/), your [religious](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/) [beliefs](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/), your [personal](http://relationships.stackexchange.com/) [life](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/) or [the rant you wrote about your boss](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/).

That said, as long as you're aware of this issue in advance, it's easy enough to avoid by following the advice given by Oded above: **use separate logins for sites you don't want linked.**

Probably the easiest and most reliable way to do this is to use the Private Browsing / Incognito feature in your browser.  Just use your normal profile for your "professional" activities on SO etc., and open a private browsing window and log in with a different e-mail address and/or OpenID provider whenever you want to post something on a site that you *don't* want linked to your SO account.

Of course, you'll generally need multiple e-mail addresses if you want to create multiple logins with the same OpenID provider, but that's pretty easy to arrange.  In particular, many e-mail providers, [including Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/12096), allow you to use an unlimited number of "address aliases" like *user+alias@gmail.com* with a single Gmail account.

(Ps. Standard warning: using two accounts to upvote each other or otherwise interact with yourself in ways that a single account wouldn't allow is considered sockpuppeting, and is forbidden by the SE TOS.  That said, as long as you keep your accounts completely separate — preferably, never even registering an account with both logins on the same site — you should be fine.)