# How can I create a secondary SE account unlinked from the main account?

Tags: support, linked-accounts

I'm trying to create an account on one of the Stack Exchange sites. However, I want to keep my professional profile separate from any personal activities.

I've tried using a secondary email address and my wife's email address to sign up. But as soon as I click on the email verification link, the browser opens up to show the account added to my existing profile.

The hide communities feature does not provide good separation, because that means I must hide everything. If I unhide professional communities, then they'd be visible in the personal profile.

How can I create a secondary account unlinked from the main account and use both on the same computer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, Stack Exchange is using cookies to keep you logged in. (This in itself is perfectly normal; pretty much all web sites that let you log in do that.) Further, due to the distributed nature of OpenID (which SE uses for authentication) it can sometimes be tricky to reliably and completely log out from SE without clearing *all* cookies from your browser.

The easiest solution for keeping two SE accounts separate is to always use the Private Browsing / Incognito mode in your browser to access your secondary account. That way, you get a fresh separate browser session with no previous cookies. (This is also the recommended way of safely logging into SE from a shared computer.)

You can also set up separate browser profiles for each of your accounts. This takes a bit more work up front, but saves you from having to log in to your secondary account again every time after closing your browser. It also lets you keep more than two accounts logged in at the same time, should that be something that you want to do.

In any case, you need to make sure to keep your logins separate. In particular, you'll probably need to manually copy and paste any email confirmation links into the correct browser window instead of just clicking them (unless you're using a web-based email client in the same browser window).

Comment: Indeed. I use two different Chrome profiles to keep my two different Stack Exchange accounts separate.

Comment: Ps. Here's a related earlier thread: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217581/why-are-all-users-stackexchange-accounts-visible

Answer (score 1):

If you are using multiple accounts, you can simply use the settings from your different accounts, as Ilmari Karonen explained.

If you aren't, then there are many browser extensions for that. I've already meet this problem and I've found the solution by asking for the useful extensions in [this](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/21236/14164) softwarerecs question.

Comment: Extension: currently the best to do is using multiple firefox profiles.